# How can I connect from a website to a Microsoft SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Ive worked with the typical PHPMyAdmin interface until now when it comes to databases.

Now Ive been handed a .bak file and pointed to "Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio" and told to use that.

My problem is that I dont know how to do the most basic things. For instance when I want to connect to a PHPMyAdmin Database I know that I need to define the host, the user, the password and the database and throw that information into a mysqli_connect() and thats that.

So my question is:

How do I connect to my database that I have in my SQL Server Managment Studio? The same way I did before? And if so where do I find the needed information like host, user, password?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is specifically designed for MySQL; it doesn't work with SQL Server. To use a .bak file, you'll need to install SQL Server (I assume Express, as you don't mention any licences). SSMS isn't SQL Server; is more like what PHPMyAdmin is for MySQL, apart from it's an application rather than a web interface. What you're asking for here, however, is far too broad for Stack Overflow, and you're effectively asking for a guide; which is off-topic here as well. You might be better off posting a topic on http://dba.stackexchange.com, but be more specific and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I've had luck using SQLSRV, PDO drivers to connect to SQL Server

Comment: Do you want to administrate it or do you have to build it into your website?

Comment: @atoms Thanks! Seems just like the function im looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would install the [SQLSRV PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) extension. Then use a similar methodology to access the database

```
$database = "";
$server = "";
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$server ; Database = $database", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE MemberID =:MemberID";

$iMemberID = 5;

$st = $conn->prepare($sql);

//named placeholders within the execute() as an array.
   $st->execute(array(':MemberID'=>$iMemberID));
//OR using bind param..
   $st->bindParam(':MemberID', $iMemberID);

while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: That seems great and easy to understand! Thanks!